# ORA-00955 error after dropping table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm running oracle SQL 11g, I'm trying to drop a table so I can redo my whole database. I've tried the following commands.

```
DROP TABLE orders AND ORDERS
ALTER TALBE DROP ORDERS
DROP TABLE ORDERS
ALTER TABLE PURGE ORDERS
```

When I tried adding in the new table I get this error

> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object.

Comment: just use DROP TABLE orders

Comment: Although there may be Oracle wizards here, not everyone know by heart what ORA-00955 is (there are many **thousands**), so adding the full error message will certainly help us to help you faster.

Comment: Please query dba_objects for this table. it will show any record if table exists in database. also one time purge dba_recycelbin;

Comment: So, you've tried all those fancy commands, and what were their results?

Comment: As [documented in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9003.htm#SQLRF01806) `DROP TABLE ORDERS;` would be correct. What was the error you got when you used that?

Comment: You can't change a object after dropped it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> " I've tried the following commands."

Use the right command and it works:

```
SQL> desc orders
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ORDER_NO                                  NOT NULL NUMBER
 ORDER_DATE                                NOT NULL DATE

SQL> drop table orders;

Table dropped.

SQL> desc orders
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object orders does not exist


SQL>
```

So if it doesn't work for you, what are you doing wrong?

1. Maybe the table was created using double-quotes for the name, so it's really  called `"Orders"` or something.
2. Maybe you're not actually running the command you think you're running. Your examples don't have a terminating character: in SQL*Plus we need to end the command with `;` or (on the next line) `/` to execute the command. That should be easy enough to check, because Oracle will tell you `Table dropped.` if, you know, you've actually dropped the table.

Answer (score 1):

This means that your drop table statement was not successfull and your table still exists. Probably because the drop would have violated some foreign keys constraints or you are simply lacking the required rights to drop the table.

Answer (score 1):

`ORA-00955` is already used by an existing object

> An attempt was made to create a database object (such as a table,
>   vies) that already exists. A user's database objects must have
>   distinct names.
>
> Action: Enter a unique name for the database object or modify or drop
>   the existing object so it can be reused.

If there is an attempt to create an existing database object, `ORA-00955` will be thrown..

**so you should delete the table first**

```
DROP TABLE TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: I found the solution. I didn't use a ; at the end of the command.

Comment: this is your error message ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object. it's not about your solution. But If you are running the script in its entirety, the editor must see the end of the line  so that you can switch to the new line.